# How can we write JPA query for below SQL query

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.0

how to write jpa query for below sql without using native sql query

select * from emp where emp_id=123 and (emp_name="ABC" OR emp_name is NULL) order by salary

Answer (score 0):

If we say

```
A and (B or C) <=> (A and B) or (A and C)
```

then you query must look like this one below

```
Employee findByEmp_idAndEmp_nameOrEmp_idAndEmp_nameIsNullOrderBySalary(Long empId, String empName);
```